# Is it normal that my mining function is looping indefinitely?

Tags: c++, hash, data-mining, sha256, cryptocurrency

So i am trying to implement a cryptocurrency for a school project but i am stuck at the block validation part, the mining. I used this code i found online and i adapted it to my project:

```
void Block::MineBlock(int nDifficulty)
{
std::string cstr(nDifficulty + 1, '\0');
for (int i = 0; i < nDifficulty; i++)
{
    cstr[i] = '0';
}
cstr[nDifficulty] = '\0';

std::string str(cstr);

do
{
    nNonce++;
    blockHash = generateHash();
} while (blockHash.substr(0, nDifficulty) != str);
this->checked = true;
}
```

My nDifficulty is set to 1. Is it normal that it is looping indefinetely?
Here is the generateHash function as well:

```
std::string Block::generateHash()
{
std::stringstream ss;
ss << index << timestamp << filename << nNonce << prevHash;
return sha256(ss.str());
}
```

Comment: If you want to remove the last character in a `std::string`, use `std::string::pop`. Don't set the last character to `\0` - that won't change the size.

Comment: This code loops indefinitely if no nonce produces a hash that meets the difficulty requirement. That's quite common.

Comment: Then does anybody know how to make a function that would actually hash easier?

Answer (score 0):

Your `str` variable is of length `nDifficulty + 1`.

So it could never compare equal to a sub-string of length `nDifficulty`, and the loop condition will never be false.